# Angular 2 getting the following error object doesn't support 'Import'

Tags: angular

Using Angular2 , I am getting an error in IE10 -but working fine with Chrome- :
"Object doesn't support property or method 'import'"
at line : System.import('app.js') in index.html  see the html code below 
please help

---index.html----

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Inventory App</title>
      <script src="vendor/system.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      System.import('app.js');
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a plnkr? What version of each lib are you using? Those seems to be quite old. Anyway, the docs [were updated](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) so you can follow it to have a working set up.

Answer (score 0):

This issue existed in 0.16, have it updated to current which is 0.19.